# Getting total count of column values looking backwards in yearly/n intervals based on composite groupby operation

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a table where each user has an unique enrollment date as shown in the table below. The user also has a service date associated with each line which contains multiple diagnosis codes (including but not limited to a finite set of string values for example, dx_A, dx_B, dx_C,...dx_N; only dx_{A,B,C} shown here for clarity) in columns associated with each service date.

| user_id | enroll_date | service_date | Code_1 | Code_2 | Code_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2019-01-30 | 2018-06-15 | dx_A | dx_B | dx_C |
| A | 2019-01-30 | 2017-05-20 | dx_B | dx_B | dx_A |
| A | 2019-01-30 | 2017-01-15 | dx_B | dx_B | dx_B |
| A | 2019-01-30 | 2018-02-10 | dx_A | dx_C | dx_A |
| A | 2019-01-30 | 2017-12-14 | dx_C | dx_B | dx_B |
| B | 2018-03-07 | 2017-02-01 | dx_A | dx_C | dx_B |
| B | 2018-03-07 | 2016-10-25 | dx_C | dx_A | dx_C |
| B | 2018-03-07 | 2016-05-25 | dx_B | dx_C | dx_A |
| B | 2018-03-07 | 2018-01-30 | dx_A | dx_A | dx_B |

Now, using pandas, I want to find out total count of each code that occur for each user looking back at 1 year, 2 year and 3 year intervals from the enroll date so the resulting table looking something like the one given below.

| user_id | dx_A_1_yr | dx_A_2_yr | dx_A_3_yr | dx_B_1yr | dx_B_2yr | dx_B_3yr | dx_C_1yr | dx_C_2yr | dx_C_3yr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 2 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 0 |

In particular, I am having trouble fetching relevant rows which is based on service date for each each user, enroll_date combination for yearly intervals looking back in time.

Example from table above, for user A looking at interval for the first year between 2018-01-30 to 2019-01-30, the condition is satisfied by rows 1 and 4 and the count for codes is hence populated accordingly from these two rows for the first year for user A. For the same user, for the 2nd year interval 2018-01-30 to 2017-01-30 the condition is satisfied by rows 2 and 5 and so on for all the users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did :

- I create new columns 'dx_A', 'dx_B' and 'dx_C' with the number of times the code is present in each row.
- For each year, I use .loc to filter the service_dates where the delay is in the asked year.
- Then I use groupby to have one row of A and another of B
- I rename the columns with a suffix according to the year
- Finally, I concatenate all the yearly dataframes and write 0 value where there is none.

The table is named 'table'

```
for code in ['dx_A', 'dx_B', 'dx_C']:
    table[code] = (table == code).sum(axis=1)
table = table.drop(['Code_1', 'Code_2', 'Code_3'], axis=1)

result = pd.DataFrame()
for year in [1, 2, 3]:
    df_year = table.loc[(table.enroll_date < table.service_date + pd.DateOffset(years=year)) & 
                       (table.enroll_date >= table.service_date + pd.DateOffset(years=year-1))]
    result_tmp = df_year.groupby('user_id').sum().add_suffix('_' + str(year) + '_yr')
    result = pd.concat([result, result_tmp], axis=1, sort=False)

result = result.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Here is the result I got
[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have taken the code values as examples only. I don't know how many code values are there so I can't use for loop as you have suggested. There are 3 intervals and I was wondering if IntervalIndex can be used to find the result.

Comment: But thanks, I think I can work with your answer if I filter out rows first based on known codes.